# Access denied attempting to create a folder on the server

Tags: asp.net, authorization, security, webmatrix, create-directory

Every new project that the client registers the system creates a folder to store the images located in "\Images\Projects{ProjectID}" where {ProjectID} is the ID project.

I put in the folder "\Images\Projects\" a web.config to allow access to users logged on.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When creating the folder, the error is displayed:

> Access to the path
>   'e:\home\amsdarquit\Web\Images\Projects\166'
>   is denied.

166 is the project code, and the folder name.
I checked on my server, and the same is not created.

Code to create the folder

```
//Save Image
var serverPath = Server.MapPath(Href("~/Images/Projects/") + id);
Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);
imgOri.Save(Path.Combine(serverPath, fileName));
```

I have looked on the site, but found nothing to help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether 'NETWORK SERVICE' user (or the user that you run your application as) has modification rights for the parent directory on the drive.

Comment: The site is hosted on an external server.
No access to IIS or Windows user.
I tried putting in web.config "<allow users="*">" but did not appear effect.

Comment: You won't be able to create a directory if your user has not rights. I suggest trying to contact with your hosting provider and ask for the necessary rights to the parent directory.